# Prove by Induction help please???

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Can anybody help me here?

A friend asked me for help with a college problem, it is as follows:

Prove by induction that this algorithm calculates the square of a number, i.e. defining $Sq(n) = n^2$ we have:

$$Sq(n) = Sq(n-1) + 2 n-1$$ for $n > 1$

Comment: We have $(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1$ so ...

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DougM I just realised that's what was meant, I wasn't sure since it wasn't latexed

Comment: @mrnovice I had to read it twice.  Yes, proper formatting helps.

Comment: You need a foundation, or starting-point. E.g. define Sq($1)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that induction here is rather inefficient since it's quite trivial to show that $n^2 =n^2-2n + 1-1+2n = (n-1)^2+2n-1$

Proceeding instead with induction:

$P_{n}: n^2=(n-1)^2+2n-1,\quad n>1$

$n=2:$

$LHS= 2^2=4$

$RHS = 1^2+2\cdot 2-1=4 =LHS\quad$hence $P_{2}$ holds

Assume $P_n$ is true, then we must prove true $P_{n+1}$

$(n+1)^2 = n^2+2n+1 = (n-1)^2+2n-1+2n+1 =(n-1)^2+4n$

$= n^2-2n+1+4n = n^2+2n+1\quad$ as required, hence true $\forall n\in\mathbb{N_{n\geq2}}$

Answer (score 0):

$n=2$: $2^2=4$ and $1^2+2\cdot 2-1=2$. 
Suppose the equation holds for each number between 2 and $n$. Then
$n^2+2(n+1)-1= n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$.